# Gerrit error while pushing commit with egit

Tags: git, push, gerrit

While commiting with egit I have this message constantly :

> error occurred during unpacking on the remote end: error Missing blob

To prevent it I have to checkout master in a new branch, git pull, paste my last changes in this new branch and then commit push. Other developpers of my team with the same git configuration in eclipse don't have the same problem (they work on the same project).

It seems to be a gerrit problem not a git one.